# Facebook IFrame Auto Resize Still Including Scroll Bars

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-iframe

I have been trying to fix this for a while but I have had no luck. I have a facebook app (witdh: 510) that keeps including scroll bars. This is how it looks in facebook:
[image: Facebook App with white scroll bars]

There is nothing in my application that will has a width greater then 510, so I am confused as to why there is white space in the first place. I also do not understand why there is a vertical scroll bar because there is clearly enough room on page to fit the app.

In my settings for the app Auto resize is called and I have `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();` in my `window.fbAsyncInit` function. I also tried using a CSS Reset `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">` but that did not clear the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that the dimensions of your iFrame will always show the content, then you could just set:

```
<iframe src="yourpage.htm" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

*scrolling="no"* will force the iFrame to NOT show scrollbars, even if content is bigger than the frame.

That should be a sure-fire way to NOT show scrollbars, but should be used cautiously and you should know that content may end up hidden with no apparent way for the user to scroll to it, if it extends beyond the bounds of the iFrame.

--edit--

Since you apparently can't set this on Facebook, you should simply wrap the page you're loading in a wrapper div and set the height, width, and overflow properties there.

```
<div class="wrap" style="height:500px;  width:510px;  overflow:hidden;">
  your page content here
</div>
```

You can use *overflow:hidden;* for no scrollbars, or *overflow-x:hidden;* for only hiding the horizontal scrollbar, or *overflow-y:hidden;* for only hiding the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: technicly right, but until you are a developer employed by facebook you have no change to set this.

Comment: I tested the `overflow: hidden` and it does work, I just need to do it like so `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style = "overflow:hidden">`

Comment: Make sure you test that in all browsers, I have no idea how setting the style on the html element will react across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First I would inspect my iframe HTML with something like "firebug", you check all your divs and verify the "layout" tab on the left of firebug.. you will see the size of you element, your border, padding margin and so, check if everything is correct.

Now what happend to me some times is that the "auto resize" from facebook doesnt work correctly on some browsers, so it miscalculates the height, and you still have a scrollbar on the right side, so because of this scrollbar, your content becomes too large and you also get an horizontal scrollbar.

My solution to this was to specify the height of the iframe myself and not using the autoresize stuff, here is the code to do this (put at the end of your page before the closing `</body>`) :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({appId: '{{fbapp_id}}', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize({height:900});
    }, 250);

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Here the height I choosed is "900" but you have to set your own height (the height of your iframe content + some security margin like 50px or so)

Also you have to replace `{{fbapp_id}}` by your real facebook application ID.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

first, remove padding & margin from the body via css

```
body {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
```

have your content in a div which set the width to 520 (if you still get scrollbars, overflow:hidden). be carfull with padding and borders on this DIV (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html for details)

when you have very long content, it also helps to set a min-height to this div. sometimes you get vertical scrollbars, which in turn leads to a horizontal scrollbar.

on the end of your page, right befor the closing body set a

```
FB.Canvas.setSize()
```

also make sure, in your app settings you have "automatic height" (or how its called) instead of scrollbars.